# Group by and sort by three different version parts

Tags: c#, linq

I have following data:

Name - Mayor Version - Minor Version - Build version
X - 1 - 0 - 0
X - 1 - 1 - 0
X - 2 - 0 - 0
Y - 0 - 2 - 3
Y - 0 - 1 - 1
Z - 4 - 4 - 4

Now I want to get the highest Version Number with Mayor > Minor > Build grouped by name.

So the output here should be:
X - 2 - 0 - 0
Y - 0 - 2 - 3
Z - 4 - 4 - 4

How to do that in linq?
I tried to group by Name and then do a sort by Mayor, then by minor then by build and take the first() but I can't figure out the syntax here...

Comment: So you need to `GroupBy` first then `Max`?

Comment: In terms of version numbers, I'd suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderByDescending` followed with chained `ThenByDescending` calls in `Select` statement after `GroupBy`:

```
class Version
{
    public string Name {get;set;} 
    public int MajorVersion {get;set;}
    public int MinorVersion {get;set;}
    public int BuildVersion {get;set;}
}

List<Version> versions = ...;
versions
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(g => g.MajorVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(g => g.MinorVersion)
                    .ThenByDescending(g => g.BuildVersion)
                    .First())
    .ToList();
```

Or try leverage default value tuple comparer:

```
versions
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(g => (g.MajorVersion, g.MinorVersion, g.BuildVersion))
            .First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works like charm, couldnt figure out the select, thank you

Comment: @Kovu was glad to help!